# Como guardar los caracteres que genera mi codigo en c++ en un archivo .txt?

Tags: c++

me encuentro desarrollando un programa basico que me genere varios códigos aleatorios y deseo guardarlos en un archivo txt, hasta ahora tengo la parte donde me genera los codigos pero me falta guardarlos en un archivo.txt, agradeceria si me pueden ayudar

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int num,num2,num3,j,x,y,z,t;
string c;

int main(){

cout<<"\n\n Cuantos codigos desea generar? : "; //solicitando el numero de codigos
cin>>t;
cout<<"\n";

srand(time(NULL));

while(t != j){                           //Validando que el numero de codigos se cumpla
        for(int i=1;i<=15;i++){          //Determinando la longitud de los codigos(15)

        num = rand();
        num=65+rand()%(90-65);   //Limtando los caracteres ascci a letras en mayuscula (aleatorio)
        num2=48+rand()%(57-48);  //Limitando los caracteres ascci a numeros(aleatorio)
        num3=1+rand()%(3-1);     //Generando numero para determinar si se usara numeros o letras

        if(num3==1){   //Determinando si el caracter que se genera es una letra o numero (aleatorio)
            c=num;
            cout<<c;
        }
        else 
        {
            c=num2;
            cout<<c;
        }

        }

cout<<"\n";
z=j++;
}
escribir(); 
system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Compilacion:

Cuantos codigos desea generar? : 5

R3F33O70543NU7R
HIA8XR5R73FMRGS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma simplificada, el operador << envía las variables hacia donde le indica la dirección de los pico-paréntesis. Eso quiere decir que cuando haces:

```
cout << variable;
```

Lo que haces es enviar **variable** hacia **cout** que representa la salida estándar, que normalmente es la pantalla.
Si quieres enviar esa misma información hacia otro lugar (ej, un archivo) debes primero tener una referencia a dicho lugar.

Para abrir un archivo, por ejemplo, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream archivo("nombre_de_archivo.txt");
}
```

Ahora **archivo** te permite enviar datos a "nombre_de_archivo.txt" de la misma forma que **cout** anteriormente te permitía enviar datos a la pantalla.

Lo único que tienes que hacer ahora es cambiar cout << variable por:

```
archivo << variables;
```

Ahora solo sustituye todos los cout por archivo y asunto resuelto.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un flujo asociado a un fichero y mandar información como si usaras

```
cout << variable;
```

Tienes que crear una variable de tipo `ofstream` y asociarle un fichero.  Además, es importante comprobar que el fichero se ha logrado abrir con éxito usando la función `fail()`

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    std::ofstream fout("fichero.txt");

    if (fout.fail()){
        cerr << "ERROR: No se ha podido abrir o crear fichero.txt" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    // se ha abierto (o creado si no existia) con exito

}
```

Puedes consultar [la documentación de ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) para más información

Answer (score 1):

He corregido tu código para hacerlo de la manera mas simple... sin embargo, la manera mas **simple** de hacerlo **(pero no por eso la mejor, y de hecho me van a odiar muchos programadores aqui)** es la siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int num,num2,num3,j,x,y,z,t;
string c, echo, txtoutput; // declaro estas strings que me van a ayudar
txtoutput = " >> archivo.txt";
int main(){

cout<<"\n\n Cuantos codigos desea generar? : "; //solicitando el numero de codigos
cin>>t;
cout<<"\n";

srand(time(NULL));

while(t != j){                           //Validando que el numero de codigos se cumpla
        for(int i=1;i<=15;i++){          //Determinando la longitud de los codigos(15)

        num = rand();
        num=65+rand()%(90-65);   //Limtando los caracteres ascci a letras en mayuscula (aleatorio)
        num2=48+rand()%(57-48);  //Limitando los caracteres ascci a numeros(aleatorio)
        num3=1+rand()%(3-1);     //Generando numero para determinar si se usara numeros o letras

        if(num3==1){   //Determinando si el caracter que se genera es una letra o numero (aleatorio)
            c=num;
            cout<<c;
            echo = "echo ";
            echo += c;
            echo += txtoutput;
            system(echo.c_str());
        }
        else 
        {
            c=num2;
            cout<<c;
            echo = "echo ";
            echo += c;
            echo += txtoutput;
            system(echo.c_str());
        }

        }

cout<<"\n";
z=j++;
}
escribir(); 
system("pause");

return 0;

}
```